# Is there a VERY light-weight lightbox available?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm looking for an extremely light-weight lightbox for jQuery. i'm trying to create my own but i suck and my fist is about to go through the screen.... i'm talking like 5kb or less.. i know it can be done, and if i knew what i was doing i'd do it... but i'm just done for the day. So, does anyone know of one? something just for images, and nothing else, no fancy crap, no extra weight, one that simply centers the lightbox in the center of the screen with whatever picture was loaded by the link.

Comment: If it's just for images, try out the 6Kb, **very** slick Fluidbox, which mimics the beautiful Medium-style enlarging lightbox: http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many options. Check out [*Rounding Up the Top 10 jQuery Lightbox Scripts*](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts).

Comment: excellent, i found http://jquery.com/demo/grey/ by john Resig, just around 2kb in size and I've significantly reduced that already.

Comment: Grey Redux link is dead. This seems to work (direct link to js) http://swampfoot.googlepages.com/greybox.js (via http://blog.jquery.com/2006/02/10/greybox-redux/)

Comment: http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/ it is around 5KB if you remove the loading and arrow-images as you won`t need them for one picture

Comment: 1.8kb lightbox plugin https://github.com/Silver89/jQuery-lightweightLightbox

Answer (score 9):

9KB light enough?

I like [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Comment: ehh, it's around the too big mark, i know it can be done for under 5k.
i checked out colorbox before and it was my next choice.

Answer (score 7):

Try [this](http://www.cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase) one. It's called Lightcase.
This Lightbox Plugin is very easy to style as you want.

Comment: It would be nice to post a short example to help people understand how easy it would be to use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont need any Ajax support then the lightest Lightbox out there is:
Modal Lightbox
http://dev.iamntz.com/52/jquery-modal-lightbox-alternative

Answer (score 1):

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

It lets you pick the items you want and delivers a js file that just does that...

Still about 22k for images...

Comment: ahhh 22k for a script to show an image, that's just too much for me. I've got one working for 2k-3k right now. not as fancy, but does the job and does it well.

Comment: also shadowbox charges money for commercial use, so it really isn't that great IMO. It's better go to with something licensed under MIT/GPL for both personal & commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

This [light box](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/) is within the size of 2kb and its working superbly. have a look @ it

Answer (score 1):

**Slimbox 2** is my favourite lightweight lightbox script - it's only 4kb and doesn't even need code to initiate it, you simply embed the script/CSS and add `rel="lightbox"` to your `<A>` tags.

http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2