# What is a good jQuery/Ajax lightbox plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, lightbox

I am looking for a light weight, cross-browser compatible lightbox with features of displaying a pop-up window.  I want to keep the popup window to be run in the lightbox and no matter what they do in the lightbox, the lightbox should never close until it is either clicked somewhere in the black area or by simply clicking an "X" in the upper right hand corner.  Does something like this exist?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293520/jquery-is-there-a-very-light-weight-lightbox-available/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [**Fancybox**](http://fancybox.net/) for many reasons. There is a small reference at http://anirugu.blogspot.com/2010/07/jquery-lightbox-fancybox-is-best.html

There is another at http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-lightbox/demo/.

Comment: Yep, very powerful and only 15kb packed/minified.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin before and it worked well for me: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

The best multi option lightbox which I always use in all my projects is [NyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/).