# How to implement the famous light box effect with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good jQuery/Ajax lightbox plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437230/what-is-a-good-jquery-ajax-lightbox-plugin)

I'm not an JavaScript guy, but I believe that jQuery has got that cool Apple-style light box effect. Or am I wrong? How would I implement that? Are there tutorials on how to do this?

Or's there something far cooler than lightbox? (well, I've heard of it like 5 years ago)...

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of about half the questions that show up here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+lightbox . Did you search at all before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good lightbox implementation:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/